# Laravel Nova custom field vs. resource tool vs. action for something like the Google Drive Picker?

Tags: laravel-nova

At this early stage of Nova development (and w/ my limited overall experience), I'm having a hard time figuring out when each customization type should be used.  In this case...

I have a "Customer" resource, and each customer has a google_drive_folder_id.  While in index view, I'd like to click a button on the customer record item and open a [Google Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) for the customer (passing the customer's folder ID to the picker).

How is this type of thing best implemented within Nova?  Here's what I've considered:

**Custom Field** - I can create a "DrivePicker" field type which displays as a button within the index view.  All of the Javascript is housed within the custom field code, so it can display the picker on click. But it seems silly to create an entire custom field component when no data is stored in the field and it's only displayed within the index view.

**Computed HTML Field** - As of v1.0.9, you can display computed fields as HTML, so I could potentially create an html link to display the picker.  But where does the picker's Javascript go?

**Resource Tool** - It seems like the drive picker is a tool tied to a resource, but there's not really anything for me to display - just a button that triggers the picker.  I don't see how I could display the button without having to go into the resource detail screen either.

**Action** - "DisplayCustomerDrivePicker" seems like it might be a logical action.  However, checking the customer and using the dropdown menu is tedious, it would fall apart if multiple customers were selected, and there's no actual backend action to perform - so I'm not sure this is even possible.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  This is one example, but I find myself frequently relying on custom fields that hold no data, and it just doesn't feel right.  Usually, it's when I want to display a modal with some resource details without leaving the index view.